# 数字四桁のカンマ区切りの正規表現の作り方

Tags: javascript, 正規表現

数字4桁でカンマ区切りの繰り返しである条件で正規表現を作成しているのですが、1以上マッチしていると、マッチさせたくない条件のものまでマッチしてしまうのですが、4桁数字のカンマ区切りで、他のマッチしない条件があるとFalseになる正規表現の作り方を教えていただきたいです。

例）
1234,4321 (OK)
1234,212 (NG)
1223,2344, (NG)

Comment: 先頭であっても4桁以下の部分が有れば NG ということで大丈夫ですか？ 例: `123` や `123,4567`

Answer (score 0):

`'^\\d{4}(,\\d{4})*$'`で先頭の数値を含めて4桁区切りの数値のみ許容する正規表現となります。

**サンプルコード**

```
<html><body>
<script>
window.onload = (event) => {
  let re = new RegExp('^\\d{4}(,\\d{4})*$');
  let arr = ['1234,4321', '1234,212', '1223,2344,', '123,1234', '1000,2000,3000', '9999'];
  arr.forEach(s => {
    console.log('%s は %s です。', s, re.test(s) ? 'OK' : 'NG');
  });
};
</script>
</body></html>
```

**実行結果**

```
1234,4321 は OK です。
1234,212 は NG です。
1223,2344, は NG です。
123,1234 は NG です。
1000,2000,3000 は OK です。
9999 は OK です。
```

Comment: ありがとうございます！
*$で繰り返しと、数値終わりを指定させてあげればよかったんですね！
追加で質問させていただきたいのですが、数値の「\d」で\dの前に\をつけてエスケープさせているのは、記号などの文字をマッチさせないようにしているためでしょうか？？

Comment: リテラル記法だと\が一つ不要なんですね！
勉強になりましたmm

Comment: 英数字を許容させる場合には、このように数値意外にも英字を追加すればいいんですね！

/^[0-9a-zA-Z]{4}(,[0-9a-zA-Z]{4})*$/